# the entity or complex type 'x' cannot be constructed in a linq to entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, csla

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the following code since I get this error in the subject when run:

My concrete DAL:

```
public class CustomerDal : ICustomerDal
{
    public List<CustomerDto> Fetch()
    {
        using(var ctx = DbContextManager<CustomerContext>.GetManager("CustomerDB"))
        {
            var result = from r in ctx.DbContext.Customers 
                         select new CustomerDto
                         {
                             CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
                             Name = r.Name,
                             Email = r.Email
                         }

            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

My data context:

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext(string connectionName)
        : base(connectionName)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<CustomerDto> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

My DTO:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The database is a LocalDb-database with the name CustomerDB, and a table called Customer with the columns CustomerId, Name, and Email.

I did notice though that if I change the DAL-code to the following, using an Anonymous function, it runs without error, but I still don't get any data from the database:

```
    public List<CustomerDto> Fetch()
    {
        using(var ctx = DbContextManager<CustomerContext>.GetManager("CustomerDB"))
        {
            var result = (from r in ctx.DbContext.Customers 
                         select new 
                         {
                             CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
                             Name = r.Name,
                             Email = r.Email
                         }).ToList().Select(x => new CustomerDto{ CustomerId = x.CustomerId, Name = x.Name, Email = x.Email });

            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'm also using the CSLA framework but that shouldn't make any difference in this matter.

I have seen that there is similar questions in the forum, bun none that really answers my question to 100% since I'm using a DTO (which all questions I found didn't make use of from the beginning).

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: The problem is mainly that linqtoentities does not support the whole linq functionality. If you want to do things like you do with dtos,... you need to do ToList() and then select into the dto. Same for complex where mechanisms that use methods (even some in built methods supported normally by linq result in the same error)

Comment: that aside noramlly I would say your "anynymous" code should result in a result. Did you also try to debug if (from r in ctx.DbContext.Customers select r).ToList() results in nothing?

Comment: Not totally (a bit bad phrased by me probably because of that). Btw I just saw you are using [Key] in your dto? Did you try to remove that already if the error is still thrown? (as far as I read the key annotationis used by the EF, thus that could result in the EF wrongly interpreting that the customerDto is an entity)

Comment: @Thomas, well if I remove the [Key]-attribute I get the following error just Before 'return result.ToList()': "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: CSLAEFCodeFirstTest.DalEf.CustomerDto: : EntityType 'CustomerDto' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.Customers: EntityType: EntitySet 'Customers' is based on type 'CustomerDto' that has no keys defined

Comment: ..I also realized that I get no data with the first example. It goes through the Query but stops on 'return result.ToList()'. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that before you do the ToList() the query is NOT executed. It is just prepared. Thus the first ToList() is the firs ttime the query itself is really exectuted.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your CustomerDto deriving from Customer...

```
public class CustomerDto : Customer { }

public List<CustomerDto> Fetch(int categoryID)
{
    return (from p in db.Products
            select new CustomerDto()
            {
                CustomerId = r.CustomerId,
                Name = r.Name,
                Email = r.Email
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't want to inherit from Customer since I want to use a "pure" Dto which resembles the table in the database, and is simply a data carrier.